# Is it possible to have a fragment without an activity?

Tags: android

This is unlikely but it would potentially save me a lot of time to re-write the same code. 
I want to implement a UI using alert-type service (like Chathead) yet I'd still like to use my fragments. Is it possible? I know I can add views to the window but fragments?

Comment: no. fragment is hosted by a activity

Comment: Yes. We can have a Fragment without activity. This can be done by attaching a "View" to the 'WindowManager' and in that "View" we can include "Fragment".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fragments are part of the activity, so they cannot replace activity. Though they behave like activity, they cannot stand themselves. Its like view cannot itself act like activity.

[From Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a **portion of user interface in an
>   Activity**. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to
>   build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You
>   can think of a fragment as a **modular section of an activity**, which has
>   its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can
>   add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub
>   activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

I hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: Share example for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Well as people have pointed out you can't, but, you can always create 
some sort of fragment wrapper.
For example purposes:

```
    public class ActivityFragmentWrapper extends FragmentActivity {
        public static final String KEY_FRAGMENT_CLASS = "keyFragmentClass";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                String fragmentClass = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(KEY_FRAGMENT_CLASS);
                try {
                    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(fragmentClass);
                    Constructor<?> constructor = cls.getConstructor();
                    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) constructor.newInstance();
                    // do some managing or add fragment to activity
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, "bla").commit();
                } catch (Exception LetsHopeWeCanIgnoreThis) {
                }
            }
        }

        public static void startActivityWithFragment(Context context, String classPathName) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityFragmentWrapper.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_FRAGMENT_CLASS, classPathName);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

You can start it like:

```
    ActivityFragmentWrapper.startActivityWithFragment(context, SomeSpecificFragment.class.getCanonicalName().toString());
```

Of course if your fragment has another constructor you have to retrieve different
one, but that part gets easier.

Answer (score 0):

No, Fragments can't exist without an Activity. They need an activity for their entry point otherwise they can't initiate their UI components and their lifecycle can't go beyond `onAttach` and `onCreateView`